# How to shutdown all threads gracefully?

Tags: java, eclipse

From below code am able to shutdown the process.

```
ShutdownHook s1 = new ShutdownHook();
s1.attachShutDownHook();
context.registerShutdownHook();
Logger.debug("Shutting down....");
```

But now I need to shutdown all threads grace fully. So for this how can I implement the code in this existing code or how can I improve it?

Kindly, let me know if there is a way for it.

Comment: There's no universally applicable way to shut down a thread gracefully (some threads are written in a way that they *can't* be shut down gracefully). You'll have to check each type of thread in your application and check for each one how to shut it down.

Comment: Why the eclipse tag?

Comment: The mindset 'shut it down gracefully' comes up a lot. It's wrong. There is no such thing; people trip over powercables all the time. You get hard-killed. JVM can coredump. It happens. The right answer is that all your threads should be able to be aborted mid-flight at the drop of a hat without recovery. This is easier than it sounds like. For example, DB transactions abort themselves, there is no need to 'do it gracefully'. Don't edit files in-place; edit with a special 'in progress' name and then ATOMIC_MOVE them into the right place, etc.

Comment: An app designed in such a fashion 'shuts down gracefully' even if you pull the plug right out. Nothing could be more graceful than that.